# Pause jQuery slideshow on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm using the [SlideJS jQuery plugin](http://www.slidesjs.com/) to animate several divs from side to side. This plugin has an option called hoverPause, which pauses the slideshow on mouseover. This feature works great, except not for me because I moved the pagination links on top of the slideshow with an absolutely positioned div.

My problem is that clicking on prev/next arrows or any pagination bullet link does not pause the slideshow, unless you move your mouse slightly.

I tried manually triggering a mouseover event when these things are clicked, but it didn't help. I also tried adding a fourth parameter to the animate() function to make the slideshow stop in certain situations, but that didn't work either.

I've found several other slideshow plugins out there, but it seems like they're either made for images only, or they don't offer pagination like SlideJS does.

Any advice would be great. I haven't done any front-end web development in a long while. Thanks.

Comment: Got some script/html to show us?